# How to compare PHP date with MySQL date

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a phpMyAdmin database where I have a database called `Events`, in there I've got the table named `Event_table` and I have a field called `date`, which has a DATE Function used to store the date for events. I want to compare PHP's current date with the Database's `date`. E.g. Today is 2017-06-23 and this is stored in the database as it is, now I want to compare this date with PHP's date and, if they both match each other, then PHP should echo "Event Today", if it doesn't match then it should echo "No Event".

Can someone please give me fully edited code.

```
 <?php
    define ('DB_User','root');
    define ('DB_Password','password');
    define ('DB_HOST','localhost');   
    define ('DB_Name','events');

    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_User, DB_Password, DB_Name);

    if(!$con){
          die('Error Connecting');
    }
    //Don't this need remove at the end of coding...
    echo "Connected successfully";

    $date = DATE('y-m-d', strtotime("now"));

    $sql = "SELECT date FROM Event_table WHERE date = date(now())";

    $Query = mysql_query($sql);

    $Row = mysql_fetch_array($Query, MYSQL_ASSOC);

    $Compare = $Row[0];
    if ($Compare == DATE('y-m-d', strtotime("now"))) {
    echo "Yes";
    }
    else {
        echo "No";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: There is Line of Code missing above the $Query, there is a code " $Time = none;   ".

Comment: Use a `where` clause on your query. Is `time` a date or datetime?

Comment: Use the `edit` under the tags to add the missing code. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44639050/edit

Comment: I have Changed the code @Chris85 i used as well but doesn't seems to work.

Comment: `time()` gets you the current number of seconds since 1.1.1970. That your date value from the database matches that is rather unlikely. That you are comparing a human-readable date value with an integer here, is of course also part of the problem. You want to use PHP’s `date` to get a string that contains the current date formatted in the same form as your value from the database, and then compare those two.

Comment: Update the question with your new code, or is the update you made the change you made? If so that is not using a `where`..

Comment: well i tired using "Where"

Comment: @chris85 I adde the new code, but its dones't echo anything, i am able to connect to the database but i am not sure what is wrong when comparing

Comment: `CURDATE` is a SQL function, not a PHP function. Dont just paste in code, look at what you are doing before doing it. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE time = curdate();` ...  assuming `time` is `YYY-MM-DD`..

Comment: yes my database time is stored in yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Finally I Figured it out so Here is the code if anyone Need's it.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "event";

// Create connection

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

} 
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");

$compare = date("Y-m-d");
/*echo $compare;*/
$sql = "SELECT date FROM event_table WHERE date = '$compare'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Date: " . $row["date"]. "<br>";
        echo '<img src="C:\Apache24\htdocs\Teying\yes_logo.png alt="icon" />';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

You should pass the date to your query and then check if there are any results. And you should obtain your $date variable differently. See below.

```
 <?php

    # ...

    $date = (new \Date())->format('Y-m-d');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Event_table WHERE date = '$date'";

    $Query = mysql_query($sql);

    $Row = mysql_fetch_array($Query, MYSQL_ASSOC);

    if (count($Row)) {
        echo "Yes";
    }
    else {
        echo "No";
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Use `print_r($Row)` to check if results are returned (as an array)

Comment: I think it might be due to the use of Date Function??

Comment: I Figured  it out, but Thank for the Help mate